# What is the meaning of ui-g-12 ui-lg-12 ui-md-12?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have checked over the Net and in [Primefacess Grid CSS](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) But couldn't find out the abbreviation of g,lg,md

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, you can mark it as "answers the question" to inform others that it is the right answer.

Comment: Looking up these details myself a.t.m. - see also https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/gridcss?id=prefix-devices-media-query-example

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the [Primefacess forum](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=47357)

ui-lg => number of columns for a **large** screen (screen width > 1024px)

ui-md => number of columns for a **medium** screen (screen width < 1024px )

ui-g = > number of columns by **default** (or screen width < 425px if lg and md columns are define)

Answer (score 0):

ui-g-* is grid template in prime component.
xl for extra large screen,
lg for large screen and
md for medium screen.
for example :

```
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-4 ui-md-6 ui-lg-8 ui-xl-12">Col1</div>
<div class="ui-g-4 ui-md-6 ui-lg-8 ui-xl-12">Col2</div>
<div class="ui-g-4 ui-md-6 ui-lg-8 ui-xl-12">Col3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, in the context of PrimeFaces it is the grid component in PrimeFaces. PrimeNG != PrimeFaces. And your answer does not answer the question what g, lg and md does!

Comment: Kukeltje primeng or primeFcaes both of them are part of prime. and in primeFaces and primeNg grid component are the same

Comment: Yes, but the question is tagged PrimeFaces. A bug in one grid system does not have to be in the other so they are different. Thanks for editing your answer btw, but now effectively your answer is now almost identical (besides the example and less detail what a large, extra large and medium screen is)